# Regex pattern for Malaysian mobile phone Number

Tags: javascript, regex, html

Regex pattern `^(\+?6?01)[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]\-*[0-9]{7,8}$` in HTML5 input return error. I tested the regex, no errors on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) as well as in my php code. But in HTML5 it does not function as it be. My code:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name="mobile_number" type="text" pattern="^(\+?6?01)[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]\-*[0-9]{7,8}$">
```

**Error:**

> textfield.js:146 Pattern attribute value ^(+?6?01)[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]-*[0-9]{7,8}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(+?6?01)[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]-*[0-9]{7,8}$/: Invalid escape

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance for any helps offered.

My tested regex:
https://regex101.com/r/1WsVwo/1

Comment: where does leading `-?` and trailing `?` come from?

Comment: What is the goal? `[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]` is allowing pipes is that what you want? It could just be `[0-9]` if you want numbers. Also html5 patterns are full string so the `^$` should be removed.

Comment: What is `\-` supposed to mean? There's no need to escape the hyphen.

Comment: @JaromandaX I update my error.

Comment: My output for this regex to validate phone number:
"+60147834432" [Malaysian phone number]

Comment: `[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]` is incorrect. You mean `[012346789]`, which is better written as `[0-46-9]`.

Comment: @EdCottrell Ah good point, I missed the 5 wasnt there.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'am not expert in Regex. Just copy from PHP code for the same purpose.

Comment: Which browser is giving you this error?

Comment: do you see in your regex101 how it `matches a single character in the list 0|12346789` - and how you've selected PCRE rather than JAVASCRIPT flavour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems with your regex. The one causing the "invalid escape" error is that you have `\-`, but you do not need to (and should not) escape the hyphen. You should just have `-`. A proper version of your `input` is:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name="mobile_number" type="text" pattern="^(\+?6?01)[0-46-9]-*[0-9]{7,8}$">
```

[Here's a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fpsL7uoj/)

In that example, I've also replaced the group `[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]` with the cleaner and more accurate `[0-46-9]`. In a character group (like `[...]`), the pipe symbol (`|`) is just another character, with no special meaning. So, for example, `[0|1]` doesn't just match `0` or `1`; it also matches a literal `|` character, which is not what you wanted. You might find this post helpful: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/2057919)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that pipe in character class doesn't have special meaning, and will be included in the character class.

Comment: Thanks for this code! But, I find it is limited to the mobile number like (012,013,014 and etc). When I entered a fixed-line like 03,05,04 and etc, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jornes The pattern here isn't intended to cover all possible phone numbers. It's just a cleaned-up and functional version of OP's regex. If you want a more general pattern for matching phone numbers, you would need to ask a new question (but search the site first; I'm pretty sure there are some comprehensive answers to this already).

Comment: Noted with thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify, the answer of @elixenide is good enough for this question. But I do have some improvement for the regex part. First, +60 / 60 is Malaysia country calling code, then it follow by 9/10 digit number. But only one kind of number having 10 digit number after country calling code while others is 9 digit. For example:

- 60 1112345678 (number start with 11 have 10 digit)
- 60 121234567 (number that not start with 11 have 9 digit)
- 60 151234567 (number start with 15 will is not a valid phone number, it is for Digi broadband user if not mistaken)

So this is my improvement on how the regex should be

```
pattern="^(\+?6?01)[02-46-9]-*[0-9]{7}$|^(\+?6?01)[1]-*[0-9]{8}$"
```

Here are the link to regex101, [try it](https://regex101.com/r/NGKWWa/1)

My sample output in [regex101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIvSb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tested further, below regex enforce user to key in dash (`-`):

```
^(\+?6?01)[02-46-9][-][0-9]{7}$|^(\+?6?01)[1][-][0-9]{8}$
```

Enter phone number in `01Z-XXXXXXX` or `011-XXXXXXXX,` where `X` is 0 to 9 and `Z` is 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9

Answer (score -1):

because your syntax error, invalid escape - => -

this correct:

```
<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name="mobile_number" type="text" pattern="^(\+?6?01)[0|1|2|3|4|6|7|8|9]-*[0-9]{7,8}$">
```

Answer (score -1):

`<input class="mdl-textfield__input" name="mobile_number" type="text" pattern="(\+?6?01)[0-9]{7,8}">`

i change your pattern to `(\+?6?01)[0-9]{7,8}`

*Update: `(\+?6?01)[0-46-9]-*[0-9]{7,8}`

See
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f3wz5oag/1/)

Comment: you missed the `[0-4,6-9]` portion -and the optional `-`

Comment: omg, phone number of Malaysia not have number 5 :), so suprise.

Comment: no, your update only allows 8 digits after the +601, and any can be a 5 ... the format is +601 [0-4,6-9] optional - then 7 or 8 digits (0-9)